# pandas: how to groupby and aggregate using column names?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
           col1 col2 col3 col4 .... col90
 row1       1    2    3    4   ....  90
 row2       91   92   93   94  ..... 180
   ......
 row1000  1001 1002 1003 1004 .... 1090
```

I want to group the columns into groups of 3 at a time and take the mean for each row.

I proceed as follows:

I generate a list of lists

```
  [['col1','col2','col3], ['col4','col5','col6']....
    ['col88','col89','col90']]
```

I want to select these columns from the dataframe using this list of lists and compute an average for each row and generate a resultant dataframe with the original rows and one third the number of columns (the data being aggregated three columns at a time).

I think the right approach is to groupby using column names and then aggregate but I am not sure how to proceed. I would like to avoid loops. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `//`

```
df.groupby((df.columns.str[3:].astype(int)-1)//3,axis=1).sum()
Out[323]: 
       0   1    29
row1    6   4   90
row2  276  94  180
```

Comment: Thanks. Confused by // where can I find info on this operator?

Comment: Actually found I could pass a function to groupby which simplifes this. I can simply pass column names and do integer arithmetic to generate the group names

Comment: Thanks. I am still transitioning from python2 so I was confused by it.